# AWS Batch cannot create c5d.18xlarge instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-batch

I'm trying to submit job with **c5d.18xlarge** **(vcpus: 72, memory: 144000)** but it never coming up till 20 mins even my maximum vcpus of compute enviroment is **256**?

```
let containerInfo = {
    jobDefinition: '',
    jobName: '',
    jobQueue: ,
    parameters: {
        companyId: params.companyId
    },
    containerOverrides: {
        vcpus: 72,
        memory: 144000
    }
}
```

Comment: I expect that would be OnDemand right?

Comment: In what region are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Lamanus yap, OnDemand with `managed` by AWS.

Comment: @Uberhumus `ap-southeast-2`

Comment: An in the Batch Compute Environment, what 'Instance types' are allowed?

Comment: @Uberhumus I've chosen `optimal`